# Number of loops in a type of directed multigraph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs, multigraphs

I am interested in finite directed multi-graphs with one connected component, where each vertex comes with exactly 1 edge pointing out from it, which can point to another vertex, or itself.  So self-loops as well as loops between neighbors are allowed, for example 1-->2 and 2-->1. Note that there is no restriction on the number of edges pointing into a vertex. The only rule is that exactly 1 edge must be pointing out of each vertex. For this type of a graph (does it have a name?), I believe that

```
(# of edges) - (# of vertices) + 1 = (# of loops)
```

Here loops and cycles are the same, and can be any size. (I believe the tetrahedron is not possible for this family of graphs)

Can anyone prove this or find a counter-example?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that a loop could be a self loop (size 1) or a loop consisting of n verticies and n nodes (size n)? If so then it is trivial to provide a counter example. Two verticies connected only to themselves. #edges = 2, #nodes = 2, while #loops=2. 2-2+1≠2.

Comment: Loops of any size are considered. Your  example consists of two connected components, but this family is restricted to just one connected component.

Comment: Here's really what I am trying to say: Consider a directed graph of size N. There are N nodes. Every node has one 'out'. Not all nodes have an 'in'. Some nodes have many 'ins'. The total number of 'outs' is equal to the total number of nodes. If there were 'outs' that had no corresponding 'in' then there is no node to receive the 'out'. To avoid ghost 'outs' and 'ins' then each 'in' is due to exactly one 'out'. If all edges are counting all 'in'-'out' pairs, then #edges=(#in+#out)/2=2N/2=N. Thus #edge-#node+1=N-N+1=1.

Comment: So you’re saying the number of loops must be 1. That’s interesting.

Comment: Can these two node sequences be simultaneously valid? 1->2->3->1 and 4->5->6->4?

Comment: Yes, your graphs consist of a single loop with trees growing out of it. A tree by itself will not work, because the root of the tree must also have an out. So you need a "ground loop" to provide the outs for the roots. But sinces the outs on the loop just lead around it, the only way to leave the loop is to climb - following a directed edge in the other direction. But when you do, you've just traversed the sole out of the node you've reached. So the only new place to go is to climb higher.

Comment: If you had two connected loops, you would have to climb up from one then go down to the other. But "down" is always the way you came, which leads back to the first loop. So you cannot connect to a second loop.